# run puppet resource types only when file has changed

Tags: puppet

I feel like this is a very common scenario but yet I haven't found a solution that meets my needs. I want to create something that works like  below. (Unfortunately *set_variable_only_if_file_was_changed* doesn't exist)

```
file { 'file1':
      path => "fo/file1",
      ensure => present,
      source => "puppet:///modules/bar/file1",
      set_variable_only_if_file_was_changed  => $file_change = true
}

if $file_change{
    file{'new file1'
        ...
    }
    exec{'do something1'
        ...
    }
    package{'my package'
        ...
    }
}
```

I have seen how exec can be suppressed using the refreshonly  => true but with files it seems harder. I would like to avoid putting code into a .sh file and execute it through a exec.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with Puppet off the top of my head. This is possible with Ansible though by capturing the output and using it to create `when` conditionals for future tasks. @Cez That is not what he is asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet does not have the feature you describe.  Resources that respond to refresh events do so in a manner appropriate to their type; there is no mechanism to define custom refresh behavior for existing resources.  There is *certainly* no way to direct which resources will be included in a node's catalog based on the results of applying other resources -- as your pseudocode seems to suggest -- because the catalog is completely built before anything in it is applied.

Furthermore, that is not nearly as constraining as you might suppose if you're coming to Puppet with a substantial background in scripting, as many people do.  People who think in terms of scripting need to make a mental adjustment to Puppet, because Puppet's DSL is definitely not a scripting language.  Rather, it is a language for describing the construction of a machine state description (a catalog).  It is important to grasp that such catalogs describe details of the machine's target state, *not* the steps required to take it from its current state to some other state.  (Even `Exec`s, a possible exception, are most effective when used in that way.)  It is very rare to be unable to determine a machine's intended state from its identity and initial state.  It is uncommon even for it to be difficult to do so.

How you might achieve the specific configuration you want depends on the details.  Often, the answer lies in user-defined facts.  For example, instead of capturing whether a given file was changed during catalog application, you provide a fact that you can interrogate during catalog building to evaluate whether that file *will* be changed, and adjust the catalog details appropriately.  Sometimes you don't need such tests in the first place, because Puppet takes action on a given resource only when changes to it are needed.

Comment: Quick summary: you should not need this functionality if you do the high-level design appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your response and clarifications!! What I am trying to solve is this: Our server code (rails) is deployed as a tar file (puppet file resource), tar file is extracted (puppet exec) and database is migrated (puppet exec). On an upgrade we are pushing a new tar-file to the puppet master and let puppet update the server. I am trying to solve the issue with having the old server still running until the new server code has been unpacked.

Comment: @alfthan, two alternatives strike me right away: (1) instead of doing a tarball install, package up your application properly (RPM / DEB / whatever) and have Puppet manage the *package* instead of the bits within.  Or (2) create a fact that examines the deployed app to determine its version, and use that to determine whether to put the `File` and `Exec` resources into the catalog.  I'm inclined to favor (1).